# SSRS Tablix border size inconsistent

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am using a totally standard tablix table (no embedded sub-tables or anything) in a SSRS report with a 1pt solid border around all cells which looks as I would expect during preview with consistent borders.

But when I deploy the report and run it, the borders are inconsistent with a thicker horizontal border line appearing every two or three rows, and the external borders also being inconsistent.

I see the same in Edge and Chrome.

Any ideas?
[example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4S9M.png)

Comment: have you tried to set all the borders to none and then reset the borders?

Comment: What's the height of your text box? .25in? Does it look correct if you zoom to 100% or when you export to excel? I think it's a rendering issue with anti-aliasing.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, been on holiday. Thanks for your responses... @Harry I have started with a totally brand new table, just a 1pt lightgrey border all around and I see the same.

Comment: @HannoverFist I see the same however I set the zoom, however if I export to excel, the borders are all showing consistently again... So I assume that would point to rendering as you suggest? The text box is 0.6cm (standard) but I have tried increasing and decreasing by 0.1cm but see the same.

Comment: I would try changing the text box height to `.25in` to see if that helps. The `6mm` is `.23622 in ` which may be causing the rendering issue. I believe the formatting was created with the Imperial system in mind and the conversion to Metric causes formatting issues like this.

Comment: I got the same problem. The border width works properly if I switch to IE explore. It seems ssrs css not working properly in Chrome/Edge

Comment: Looks like you are spot on there @SheldonZh. I raised this via the feedback form in Edge but no sure if that will do anything!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the border width to 0.5pt, this worked for me.

Comment: I have the same problem. I did what you suggested, but it still happens

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I solved it by avoiding overlapping of borders of subsequence cells.
Mainly you don't need top border at all.
And you don't need right border for all cells except the right most one.

Here is my settings looks like:
For all cells :
[Boarder Style Setting For All Cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXsqf.png)

For right most cell:

[Boarder Style Setting For Right Most Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uk8n.png)

The border of my top most row is covered by border of header row.
Hope it helps.